# My Ajax script calls on my php but not sure if my PHP file is being ran

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to make sure that my ajax is properly calling my PHP file. My php file is supposed to print items on the console as well as send data to mysql. Neither are happening and I wonder is it because my Ajax isn't properly calling it?

None of my echos print on the console making me believe that it isn't running.

### JS File

```
 var dataString = JSON.stringify(survey.data);
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

     $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
             url: "connect.php",
             data: {dataString},
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
             $('#response pre').html( data );
         },
         error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
         //    console.log( errorThrown );
         }
     });
```

### Connect.php

```
<?php

echo '$test';

echo '<script>console.log("Your stuff here")</script>';

$json = (file_get_contents("php://input"));

$obj = json_decode($json,true);


header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")


$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "arc";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


 ?>
```

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser's debugging tools.  Is the AJAX request being made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is it what you expect?  Are there any errors in your PHP logs?  It also looks like you're trying to read the request body in a GET request, but a GET has no request body.

Comment: You're using functions that don't exist any more in PHP. No more `mysql_*` for quite some time now.

Comment: Also syntax errors in the PHP including bad quotes.

Comment: @David the network tab shows the data that I want being posted to the php file, server status is 200, type xhr. How can I check the php logs in the browser?

Comment: @miken32 Thanks updated it, vscode isn't showing any errors for me. How can I fix my syntax errors?

Comment: @whatstheword: You check the PHP logs on the server.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: Once you do that you'll see fatal errors about missing semicolons. Once you fix that you'll see warnings about setting a header after sending content.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

1. If you want to send JSON to the server, you shouldn't put the `data:` parameter in an object. It should be

   ```
   data: dataString,
   ```

   When you use an object, it converts it to URL-encoded format, so it was sending `dataString=<your JSON>`, which is not valid JSON so `json_decode()` in the PHP script was failing. You could have used:

   ```
   $obj = json_decode($_POST['dataString'], true);
   ```

   to get it instead of reading from `php://input`.
2. Since you have

   ```
   dataType: 'json',
   ```

   in the AJAX call, jQuery will try to parse the response as JSON. If the parse fails it won't call your `success:` callback (if you provide an `error:` callback it will call it). Since you're returning HTML, use

   ```
   dataType: 'html',
   ```

   instead.

   If this is just for testing, you could leave it as it is, and use the Network tab of the browser's Developer Tools to see whether it called the script and what the raw response was.